# How to insert a .html into same page using html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I'm trying to fix this code to show the content of Pages 1 and 2 when the buttons are pushed. I have these code segments and I hope you can help me. I'm trying to show the result into `mainElement` if possible:

I tried with this code and it doesn't work.

```js
const button1 = document.getElementById('button-1');
const button2 = document.getElementById('button-2');
const mainElement = document.querySelector('main');

button1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  fetch('./page1.html')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(html => {
      mainElement.innerHTML = html;
    });
});

button2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  fetch('./page2.html')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(html => {
      mainElement.innerHTML = html;
    });
});
```

```html
<span>
  <nav>
    <li><button class="route-button" id="button-1">Page 1</button></li>
    <li><button class="route-button" id="button-2">Page 2</button></li>
    <li><button class="route-diver"><a href="./divertidos.html" alt="Scripts divertidos (con los que practico)">Divertidos </a></button></li>
  </nav>
</span>
```

Comment: There's no `<main>` in the HTML you postd.

Comment: The code looks OK to me. Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: How exactly does it _not work_? What do you expect to happen vs what actually happens?

Comment: make sure your js is after the dom markup or add into the domcontentloaded event

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the main element. Perhaps you meant to add it after the button?

```
<span>
  <nav>
    <li><button class="route-button" id="button-1">Page 1</button></li>
    <li><button class="route-button" id="button-2">Page 2</button></li>
    <li><button class="route-diver"><a href="./divertidos.html" alt="Scripts divertidos (con los que practico)">Divertidos </a></button></li>
  </nav>
</span>
<main></main>
```

Comment: While this is possible, I think it's more likely that he just didn't copy it into the question.